# Search Engine in PHP having new architecture

Tags: php, search

I have invented and implemented a new search engine architecture.

This search engine has been developed mainly for English Alphabet. This search engine is based on the fact that no letter in English Alphabet has more than 30,000 words starting with it. This search engine works on text/html files only.

Please review the code. The code is below:

---

### create_index_directories.php

```
<?php

/* This program creates index directories for storing index files.
 * Required argument: Path to directory where the top level index
 * directory and its subdirectories will be created. The top level index
 * directory will be named index_directory.
 */

$num_directories_given = 0;
$index_dir = "";

function print_usage()
{
    echo ("Usage:\n\n" .
          "  Syntax:\n\n" .
          "    create_index_directories [OPTIONS] [dir_path]\n\n" .
          "  Description:\n\n" .
          "    create_index_directories creates index directories for storing index files.\n" .
          "    \"dir_path\" is the path to directory where the top level index directory\n" .
          "    and sub directories will be created. The top level index directory will\n" .
          "    be named index_directory.\n\n" .
          "  Options:\n\n" .
          "    --help\n" .
          "      Print this usage/help and exit.\n");
} // end of print_usage

for ($i = 1; $i < $argc; $i++) {
    //echo "Option " . $i . ": " . $argv[$i] . "\n";
    $arg = $argv[$i];
    if ($arg[0] === '-') {
        if ($arg === "--help") {
            print_usage();
            exit(0);
        } else {
            echo "create_index_directories: Unknown option: " . $arg . "\n";
            echo "Try create_index_directories --help to see the help.\n";
            exit(1);
        }
    } else {
        $index_dir = $arg;
        $num_directories_given++;
    }
} // end of for loop

if ($num_directories_given == 0) {
    echo "create_index_directories: One directory argument is required.\n";
    echo "Try create_index_directories --help to see the help.\n";
    exit(1);
} else if ($num_directories_given > 1) {
    echo "create_index_directories: \"Only one directory\" argument is required.\n";
    echo "Try create_index_directories --help to see the help.\n";
    exit(1);
}

if (is_dir($index_dir) != TRUE) {
    echo "create_index_directories: \"" . $index_dir . "\" is not a directory.\n";
    echo "Try create_index_directories --help to see the help.\n";
    exit(1);
}

$create_dir = $index_dir . "/index_directory";
if (file_exists($create_dir) != TRUE) {
    if (mkdir($create_dir) != TRUE) {
        echo "create_index_directories: Failed to create directory \"" . $create_dir . "\". Exiting...\n";
        exit(1);
    } else {
        echo "Created directory " . $create_dir . "\n";
    }
} else {
    echo $create_dir . " already exists.\n";
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $sub_dir = $create_dir . "/" . $i;
    if (file_exists($sub_dir) != TRUE) {
        if (mkdir($sub_dir) != TRUE) {
            echo "create_index_directories: Failed to create directory \"" . $sub_dir . "\". Exiting...\n";
            exit(1);
        } else {
            echo "Created directory " . $sub_dir . "\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo $sub_dir . " already exists.\n";
    }
}

foreach (range('a', 'z') as $letter) {
    $sub_dir = $create_dir . "/" . $letter;
    if (file_exists($sub_dir) != TRUE) {
        if (mkdir($sub_dir) != TRUE) {
            echo "create_index_directories: Failed to create directory \"" . $sub_dir . "\". Exiting...\n";
            exit(1);
        } else {
            echo "Created directory " . $sub_dir . "\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo $sub_dir . " already exists\n";
    }
}

?>
```

---

### create_index_or_add_to_existing_index.php

```
<?php

/* This program takes files/directories as arguments and parses the
 * files (present in directories or given on command line) to create the
 * search index files. The directories are processed recursively if -r option
 * is given. This program also requires the path to directory where
 * a directory called index_directory exists. This index_directory
 * contains 36 folders named 0, 1, 2, .., 9 and a, b, c, .., y, z.
 * Index files are created in subdirectories of index_directory.
 * This program works on text/html files only. You can use program
 * create_index_directories.php to create index_directory and its subdirectories.
 */

// error handler function
function custom_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    //echo "Got error/notice/warning, etc. Exiting..\n";
    echo "Got error/notice/warning, etc.\n";
    echo $errno. "\n";
    echo $errtsr . "\n";
    echo $errfile . "\n";
    echo $errline . "\n";
    //echo "Exit status is 1.\n";
    //exit(1);
} // end of custom_error_handler
// set to the user defined error handler
$old_error_handler = set_error_handler("custom_error_handler");

function print_usage()
{
    echo ("Usage:\n\n" .
          "  Syntax:\n\n" .
          "    create_index_or_add_to_existing_index OPTION[S] [FILE...] [DIR...]\n\n" .
          "  Description:\n\n" .
          "    create_index_or_add_to_existing_index parses a file and creates search index files\n" .
          "    or adds to already existing index files. It works on text/html files only.\n" .
          "    The file can be given as an argument or it may be present in a directory\n" .
          "    which itself has been given as an argument. This program also requires\n" .
          "    the path to directory where a directory called index_directory\n" .
          "    and its subdirectories (0-9, a-z) exist. You can use\n" .
          "    program create_index_directories.php to create index_directory\n" .
          "    and its subdirectories. The paths to file/dir to be indexed should be\n" .
          "    relative to server_root_directory_path (to be given by specifying -s option).\n\n" .
          "  Options:\n\n" .
          "     -i path_to_index_directory (MANDATORY option)\n" .
          "        Use -i option to specify the path to directory where directory\n" .
          "        called index_directory and its subdirectories (0-9, a-z) exist.\n" .
          "        Index files are created in subdirectories of index_directory.\n\n" .
          "     -r\n" .
          "        Specify -r option to process directory/directories recursively.\n\n" .
          "     -p prefix_path\n" .
          "        Please give a prefix to add before the file path that will be written to\n" .
          "        index files. It could be something like https://mywebsite.com. If the\n" .
          "        file path abcd/tyr.html is going to be written to index file then it\n" .
          "        will actually write https://mywebsite.com/abcd/tyr.html in the index\n" .
          "        file if -p option is present.\n\n" .
          "     -s server_root_directory_path (MANDATORY option)\n" .
          "        The \"absolute\" path to server root directory (from where index.html or index.php will be served).\n" .
          "        The paths to file/dir to be indexed should be relative to server_root_directory_path.\n\n" .
          "    --help\n".
          "        Print this usage/help and exit.\n\n" .
          " So, basically the file to be indexed is found by combining server_root_directory_path\n" .
          " and path to files/directories given on command line while the file contents\n" .
          " to be written is formed by combining prefix and path to files/directories given\n" .
          " on command line.\n");
} // end of print_usage

$iOptionPresent = FALSE;
$rOptionPresent = FALSE;
$pOptionPresent = FALSE;
$sOptionPresent = FALSE;
$index_dir_parent = "";
$index_dir = "";
$prefix = "";
$server_root_path = "";
$file_dir_array = array();
$num_files_processed = 0;

for ($i = 1; $i < $argc; $i++) {
    echo "debug: Argument/Option " . $i . ": " . $argv[$i] . "\n";
    $arg = $argv[$i];
    if ($arg[0] === '-') {
        if ($arg === "--help") {
            print_usage();
            exit(0);
        } else if ($arg === "-r") {
            $rOptionPresent = TRUE;
        } else if ($arg === "-i") {
            $iOptionPresent = TRUE;
            if (($i+1) < $argc) {
                $index_dir_parent = $argv[$i+1];
                $index_dir = $index_dir_parent . "/" . "index_directory";
                $i++;
                continue;
            }
        } else if ($arg === "-p") {
            $pOptionPresent = TRUE;
            if (($i+1) < $argc) {
                $prefix = $argv[$i+1];
                if ((substr($prefix, -1, 1) != "/") && (substr($prefix, -1, 1) != "\\")) {
                    $prefix = $prefix . "/";
                }
                $i++;
                continue;
            }
        } else if ($arg === "-s") {
            $sOptionPresent = TRUE;
            if (($i+1) < $argc) {
                $server_root_path = $argv[$i+1];
                if ((substr($server_root_path, -1, 1) != "/") && (substr($server_root_path, -1, 1) != "\\")) {
                    $server_root_path = $server_root_path . "/";
                }
                $i++;
                continue;
            }
        } else {
            echo "create_index_or_add_to_existing_index: Unknown option: " . $arg . "\n";
            echo "Try create_index_or_add_to_existing_index --help to see the help.\n";
            exit(1);
        }
    } else {
        array_push($file_dir_array, $arg);
    }
} // end of for loop

// debug info
echo "\nDEBUG_INFO_START:\n\n";
if ($rOptionPresent === TRUE) {
    echo "-r option is present.\n";
} else {
    echo "-r option is NOT present.\n";
}
if ($iOptionPresent === TRUE) {
    echo "-i option is present.\n";
    echo "index_dir_parent = " . $index_dir_parent . "\n";
} else {
    echo "-i option is NOT present.\n";
}
if ($pOptionPresent === TRUE) {
    echo "-p option is present.\n";
    echo "prefix = " . $prefix . "\n";
} else {
    echo "-p option is NOT present.\n";
}
if ($sOptionPresent === TRUE) {
    echo "-s option is present.\n";
    echo "server_root_path = " . $server_root_path . "\n";
} else {
    echo "-s option is NOT present.\n";
}
$num_entries = count($file_dir_array);
echo "Entries in file_dir_array are:\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_entries; $i++){
    echo $file_dir_array[$i] . "\n";
}
echo "\nDEBUG_INFO_END\n\n";
// end debug info

if ($index_dir_parent == "") {
    echo "create_index_or_add_to_existing_index: Please give the path to directory where index_directory exist.\n";
    echo "Try create_index_or_add_to_existing_index --help to see the help.\n";
    echo "Exiting..\n";
    exit(1);
}

if ($server_root_path == "") {
    echo "create_index_or_add_to_existing_index: Please give the path to server root directory.\n";
    echo "Try create_index_or_add_to_existing_index --help to see the help.\n";
    echo "Exiting..\n";
    exit(1);
}

if (file_exists($index_dir_parent) != TRUE) {
    echo "create_index_or_add_to_existing_index: \"" . $index_dir_parent . "\" does not exist.\n";
    echo "Please give a valid path to directory where index_directory exist.\n";
    echo "Try create_index_or_add_to_existing_index --help to see the help.\n";
    echo "Exiting..\n";
    exit(1);
}

if (is_dir($index_dir_parent) != TRUE) {
    echo "create_index_or_add_to_existing_index: \"" . $index_dir_parent . "\" is not a directory.\n";
    echo "Please give a valid path to directory where index_directory exist.\n";
    echo "Try create_index_or_add_to_existing_index --help to see the help.\n";
    echo "Exiting..\n";
    exit(1);
}

if (file_exists($index_dir) != TRUE) {
    echo "create_index_or_add_to_existing_index: \"index_directory\" does not exist in \"" . $index_dir_parent . "\".\n";
    echo "Please give a valid path to directory where index_directory exist.\n";
    echo "Try create_index_or_add_to_existing_index --help to see the help.\n";
    echo "Exiting..\n";
    exit(1);
}

if (is_dir($index_dir) != TRUE) {
    echo "create_index_or_add_to_existing_index: index_directory \"" . $index_dir . "\" is not a directory.\n";
    echo "Please give a valid path to directory where index_directory exist.\n";
    echo "Try create_index_or_add_to_existing_index --help to see the help.\n";
    echo "Exiting..\n";
    exit(1);
}

if (count($file_dir_array) < 1) {
    echo "create_index_or_add_to_existing_index: No files/directories given for indexing.\n";
    echo "Try create_index_or_add_to_existing_index --help to see the help.\n";
    exit(0);
}

// Check if all index directories exist
echo "create_index_or_add_to_existing_index: checking whether all index directories exist..\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {

    $sub_dir = $index_dir . "/" . $i;
    if (file_exists($sub_dir) != TRUE) {
        echo $sub_dir . " does not exist.\n";
        echo "Exiting..\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    if (is_dir($sub_dir) != TRUE) {
        echo $sub_dir . " is not a directory.\n";
        echo "Exiting..\n";
        exit(1);
    }

} // end of for loop

foreach (range('a', 'z') as $letter) {

    $sub_dir = $index_dir . "/" . $letter;
    if (file_exists($sub_dir) != TRUE) {
        echo $sub_dir . " does not exist.\n";
        echo "Exiting..\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    if (is_dir($sub_dir) != TRUE) {
        echo $sub_dir . " is not a directory.\n";
        echo "Exiting..\n";
        exit(1);
    }

} // end of foreach loop

echo "All index directories exist.\n\n";

echo "\n\n**** Starting Indexing.. ****\n\n";

$num_entries = count($file_dir_array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_entries; $i++) {

    $file_rl_path = $file_dir_array[$i];
    $file = $server_root_path . $file_rl_path;

    if (file_exists($file) != TRUE) {
        echo "\"" . $file . "\" does not exist.\n";
    } else if (is_file($file) == TRUE) {
        process_file($file, $file_rl_path);
    } else if (is_dir($file) == TRUE) {
        process_dir($file);
    } else {
        echo "\"" . $file . "\": No such file or directory.\n";
    }

} // end of for loop

function process_dir($dir) {

    //echo $dir . "\n";
    $files = scandir($dir);
    if ($files == FALSE) {
        return;
    }
    $num = count($files);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
        if (($files[$i] === ".") || ($files[$i] === "..")) {
            continue;
        }
        $file_entry = $dir . "/" . $files[$i];
        if (file_exists($file_entry) != TRUE) {
            echo "\"" . $file_entry . "\" does not exist.\n";
        } else if (is_file($file_entry) == TRUE) {
            $empty_string = "";
            $root_path = $GLOBALS['server_root_path'];
            $file_rl_path = str_replace($root_path, $empty_string, $file_entry);
            //echo "Old file_rl_path  = " . $file_entry . ", New file_rl_path  = " . $file_rl_path . "\n";
            process_file($file_entry, $file_rl_path);
        } else if (is_dir($file_entry) == TRUE) {
            if ($GLOBALS['rOptionPresent'] === TRUE) {
                process_dir($file_entry);
            } else {
                //echo $file_entry . "\n"; // remove this later // TODO
            }
        } else {
            echo "\"" . $file_entry . "\": No such file or directory.\n";
        }
    } // end of for loop

} // end of process_dir

function process_file($file, $file_rl_path) {

    //echo $file . "\n";
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    if ($handle == FALSE) {
        echo "Error: Failed to open file \"" . $file . "\"\n";
        return;
    }

    echo "\n\nIndexing file \"" . $file . "\"\n";

    // read file
    $line_num = 0;
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) != FALSE) {
        /*
        //echo $line;
        $line_num++;
        $len = strlen($line);
        echo "line number " . $line_num . " length = " . $len . "\n";
        */
        $pattern = "([0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]*)";
        preg_match_all($pattern, $line, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        $match_count = count($matches);
        for ($j = 0; $j < $match_count; $j++) {
            $word = $matches[$j][0];
            //echo $word . "\n";
            $word_l = strtolower($word);
            //echo $word_l . "\n";
            process_word_l($word_l, $file, $file_rl_path);
        }
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail when reading file \"" . $file . "\"\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);

    echo "Indexing file \"" . $file . "\" completed.\n";
    $GLOBALS['num_files_processed'] = $GLOBALS['num_files_processed'] + 1; 
    echo "Total files indexed = " . $GLOBALS['num_files_processed'] . "\n";

} // end of process_file

function process_word_l($word_l, $file, $file_rl_path) {

    $letter = substr($word_l, 0 , 1);
    $dir_to_check = $GLOBALS['index_dir'] . "/" . $letter;
    $file_to_check =  $dir_to_check . "/" . $word_l;
    $content_without_newline = $GLOBALS['prefix'] . $file_rl_path;
    $content = $content_without_newline . "\n";

    //create file if file does not exist
    if (file_exists($file_to_check) != TRUE) {
        //echo "\"" . $file_to_check . "\" does not exist. Creating it..\n";
        if (file_put_contents($file_to_check, $content) == FALSE) {
            echo "Error: file_put_contents failed for file \"" . $file_to_check . "\"\n";
        }
        return;
    }

    //echo "debug: file_to_check = " . $file_to_check . "\n";
    //echo "debug: file_to_check = " . $file_to_check . "\n";
    //echo "debug: file_to_check = " . $file_to_check . "\n";
    //echo "debug: file_to_check = " . $file_to_check . "\n";

    $handle = fopen($file_to_check, "r+");
    if ($handle == FALSE) {
        echo "Error: Failed to open file \"" . $file_to_check . "\"\n";
        return;
    }

    // check if entry exists and if not then append at the end
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) != FALSE) {
        if ($line === $content) {
            //echo "Entry \"" . $content_without_newline . "\" already exists in file \"" . $file_to_check ."\"\n";
            return;
        }
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail when reading file \"" . $file_to_check . "\"\n";
    }
    fwrite($handle, $content);
    fclose($handle);

} // end of process_word_l

echo "\n\n**** Indexing complete.**** \n\n";

?>
```

---

### search_index.php

```
<?php

/* This program searches for search words in index files. This program
 * requires the path to directory where a directory called index_directory exists.
 * This index_directory contains 36 subdirectories named 0, 1, 2, .., 9 and a, b, c, .., y, z.
 * The index files are present in these subdirectories.
 */

function print_usage()
{
    echo ("Usage:\n\n" .
          "  Syntax:\n\n" .
          "    search_index OPTION[S] [search_word[s]...]\n\n" .
          "  Description:\n\n" .
          "    search_index searches for search_word[s] in index files. One or more\n" .
          "    search words can be specified. This program requires the path to directory\n" .
          "    where a directory called index_directory and its subdirectories (0-9, a-z)\n" .
          "    exist. The index files are present in these subdirectories.\n\n" .
          "  Options:\n\n" .
          "    -i path_to_index_directory (MANDATORY option)\n" .
          "        Use -i option to specify the path to directory where directory\n" .
          "        called index_directory exist.\n\n" .
          "    --help\n".
          "        Print this usage/help and exit.\n");
} // end of print_usage

$iOptionPresent = FALSE;
$index_dir_parent = "";
$index_dir = "";
$search_keyword_array = array();
$search_results_array = array();

for ($i = 1; $i < $argc; $i++) {
    echo "debug: Argument/Option " . $i . ": " . $argv[$i] . "\n";
    $arg = $argv[$i];
    if ($arg[0] === '-') {
        if ($arg === "--help") {
            print_usage();
            exit(0);
        } else if ($arg === "-i") {
            $iOptionPresent = TRUE;
            if (($i+1) < $argc) {
                $index_dir_parent = $argv[$i+1];
                $index_dir = $index_dir_parent . "/" . "index_directory";
                $i++;
                continue;
            }
        } else {
            echo "search_index: Unknown option: " . $arg . "\n";
            echo "Try search_index --help to see the help.\n";
            exit(1);
        }
    } else {
        array_push($search_keyword_array, $arg);
    }
} // end of for loop

// debug info
echo "\nDEBUG_INFO_START:\n\n";
if ($iOptionPresent === TRUE) {
    echo "-i option is present.\n";
    echo "index_dir_parent = " . $index_dir_parent . "\n";
} else {
    echo "-i option is NOT present.\n";
}

$num_entries = count($search_keyword_array);
echo "Entries in search_keyword_array are:\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_entries; $i++){
    echo $search_keyword_array[$i] . "\n";
}
echo "\nDEBUG_INFO_END\n\n";
// end debug info

if ($index_dir_parent == "") {
    echo "search_index: Please give the path to directory where index_directory exist.\n";
    echo "Try search_index --help to see the help.\n";
    echo "Exiting..\n";
    exit(1);
}

if (file_exists($index_dir_parent) != TRUE) {
    echo "search_index: \"" . $index_dir_parent . "\" does not exist.\n";
    echo "Please give a valid path to directory where index_directory exist.\n";
    echo "Try search_index --help to see the help.\n";
    echo "Exiting..\n";
    exit(1);
}

if (is_dir($index_dir_parent) != TRUE) {
    echo "search_index: \"" . $index_dir_parent . "\" is not a directory.\n";
    echo "Please give a valid path to directory where index_directory exist.\n";
    echo "Try search_index --help to see the help.\n";
    echo "Exiting..\n";
    exit(1);
}

if (file_exists($index_dir) != TRUE) {
    echo "search_index: \"index_directory\" does not exist in \"" . $index_dir_parent . "\".\n";
    echo "Please give a valid path to directory where index_directory exist.\n";
    echo "Try search_index --help to see the help.\n";
    echo "Exiting..\n";
    exit(1);
}

if (is_dir($index_dir) != TRUE) {
    echo "search_index: index_directory \"" . $index_dir . "\" is not a directory.\n";
    echo "Please give a valid path to directory where index_directory exist.\n";
    echo "Try search_index --help to see the help.\n";
    echo "Exiting..\n";
    exit(1);
}

if (count($search_keyword_array) < 1) {
    echo "search_index: No search word given for searching.\n";
    echo "Try search_index --help to see the help.\n";
    exit(0);
}

$num_entries = count($search_keyword_array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_entries; $i++) {
    $word = $search_keyword_array[$i];
    $word_l = strtolower($word);
    $letter = substr($word_l, 0 , 1);
    $dir_to_check = $GLOBALS['index_dir'] . "/" . $letter;
    $file_to_check =  $dir_to_check . "/" . $word_l;

    if (file_exists($file_to_check) != TRUE) {
        continue;
    }
    if (is_file($file_to_check) != TRUE) {
        continue;
    }
    $handle = fopen($file_to_check, "r");
    if ($handle == FALSE) {
        //echo "Error: Failed to open file \"" . $file_to_check . "\"\n";
        continue;
    }

    while (($line = fgets($handle)) != FALSE) {
        // remove newline from line
        $line = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $line);
        //$old_value = $search_results_array[$line];
        //if (($old_value == NULL) || ($old_value == FALSE)) {
        //    $old_value = 0;
        //}
        if (array_key_exists($line, $search_results_array) == FALSE) {
          $search_results_array[$line] = 1;
        } else {
          $search_results_array[$line]++;
        }
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail when reading file \"" . $file_to_check . "\"\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
} // end of for loop

// dump search_results_array after sorting
arsort($search_results_array);
//var_dump($search_results_array);
$keys = array_keys($search_results_array);
$num_entries = count($keys);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_entries; $i++) {
    echo $keys[$i]. "\n";
} // end of for loop

?>
```

---

### ReadMe.txt

```
Architecture of this Search Engine
----------------------------------

This search engine has a new architecture compared to other search engines.

I invented and implemented this new search engine architecture.

This search engine has been developed mainly for English Alphabet. This search
engine is based on the fact that no letter in English Alphabet has more than
30,000 words starting with it. This search engine works on text/html files only.

This search engine was mainly developed so that it could be used on websites. So,
now websites can integrate this search engine on their platform so that a user can
search anything on their website. The website can index all their pages through this
search engine and also give a search box to the user. The websites now do not have to
rely on third party search engines.

The structure of the search index is that there is a top level directory called
index_directory. This directory has 36 folders. The folders are named: 0, 1, 2, .., 8, 9 and
a, b, c, .., y, z. Every word has an index file name with the same name in the directory
which starts with the same letter as the word. So, since no letter has more than
30,000 words starting with it, there will be at max only 30,000 files in that directory.
These days modern OSes can handle many more files in one directory.

For example, if the word is "server", then there will be a file in "index_directory/s" folder
called "server". This file will contain the path of all documents that contain the word
"server".

So, the contents of the file server can be:
https://www.myexample.com/abcd.html
https://www.myexample.com/1234.html
https://www.myexample.com/hello.html

These three html documents contain the word "server". Now, if someone wants to
search for the word "server" then the contents of this file will be printed on
the output page/screen which means that these 3 documents contain the word "server".

Now, let's suppose there is another word called "hello". So, there will be a file
in "index_directory/h" called hello and this will contain the path of all documents
that contain the word "hello".

Let's suppose that the index file "hello" has following contents:
https://www.myexample.com/xyz.html
https://www.myexample.com/new.html
https://www.myexample.com/hello.html

Now, if someone search for both keywords "server" and "hello", the output will be:
https://www.myexample.com/hello.html
https://www.myexample.com/abcd.html
https://www.myexample.com/1234.html
https://www.myexample.com/xyz.html
https://www.myexample.com/new.html

So, you see that "https://www.myexample.com/hello.html" is the first URL to be
printed because it contains both "server" and "hello" words. So, the document
which contains most number of search words will be printed first and then documents
which contain less number of search words. So, basically the printing is sorted
in descending order according to the number of search words present in the document.

Programs in this Search Engine
------------------------------
There are three programs developed in PHP in this Search Engine. So, it will run
on all platforms that have PHP installed. The three programs are:

* create_index_directories.php
* create_index_or_add_to_existing_index.php
* search_index.php

* create_index_directories.php: This program creates index directories for storing
  index files. Required argument: Path to directory where the top level index
  directory and its subdirectories will be created. The top level index
  directory will be named index_directory.

  Usage:

    Syntax:
        create_index_directories [OPTIONS] [dir_path]

            Description:
                create_index_directories creates index directories for storing
                index files. "dir_path" is the path to directory where the top
                level index directory and sub directories will be created.
                The top level index directory will be named index_directory.

            Options:
                --help
                    Print this usage/help and exit

* create_index_or_add_to_existing_index.php: This program takes files/directories as arguments
  and parses the files (present in directories or given on command line) to create the
  search index files or add to already existing index files. The directories are processed
  recursively if -r option is given. This program also requires the path to directory where
  a directory called index_directory exists. This index_directory
  contains 36 folders named 0, 1, 2, .., 9 and a, b, c, .., y, z.
  Index files are created in subdirectories of index_directory. This program
  works on text/html files only. You can use program create_index_directories.php
  to create index_directory and its subdirectories.

    Usage:

        Syntax:
            create_index_or_add_to_existing_index OPTION[S] [FILE...] [DIR...]

            Description:
                create_index_or_add_to_existing_index parses a file and creates search index files
                or adds to already existing index files. It works on text/html files only.
                The file can be given as an argument or it may be present in a directory which itself has been
                given as an argument. This program also requires the path to directory
                where a directory called index_directory and its subdirectories (0-9, a-z) exist.
                You can use program create_index_directories.php to create
                index_directory and its subdirectories. The paths to file/dir to
                be indexed should be relative to server_root_directory_path
                (to be given by specifying -s option).

            Options:
               -i path_to_index_directory (MANDATORY option)
                  Use -i option to specify the path to directory where directory
                  called index_directory and its subdirectories (0-9, a-z) exist.
                  Index files are created in subdirectories of index_directory.

               -r
                  Specify -r option to process directory/directories recursively.

               -p prefix_path
                  Please give a prefix to add before the file path that will be written to
                  index files. It could be something like https://mywebsite.com. If the
                  file path abcd/tyr.html is going to be written to index file then it
                  will actually write https://mywebsite.com/abcd/tyr.html in the index\
                  file if -p option is present.

               -s server_root_directory_path (MANDATORY option)
                  The \"absolute\" path to server root directory (from where index.html or index.php will be served).
                  The paths to file/dir to be indexed should be relative to server_root_directory_path.

              --help
                  Print this usage/help and exit.

    So, basically the file to be indexed is found by combining server_root_directory_path
    and path to files/directories given on command line while the file contents
    to be written is formed by combining prefix and path to files/directories given
    on command line.

* search_index.php: This program searches for search words in index files. This program
  requires the path to directory where a directory called index_directory exists.
  This index_directory contains 36 subdirectories named 0, 1, 2, .., 9 and a, b, c, .., y, z.
  The index files are present in these subdirectories.

    Usage:

        Syntax:
            search_index OPTION[S] [search_word[s]...]

        Description:
            search_index searches for search_word[s] in index files. One or more
            search words can be specified. This program requires the path to directory
            where a directory called index_directory and its subdirectories (0-9, a-z)
            exist. The index files are present in these subdirectories.

            Options:
              -i path_to_index_directory (MANDATORY option)
                  Use -i option to specify the path to directory where directory
                  called index_directory exist.

              --help
                  Print this usage/help and exit.

Example
-------
There are three programs developed in PHP in this Search Engine. So, it will run
on all platforms that have PHP installed. I have used xampp/PHP on Windows to
develop this search engine so I will give an example on how to use it on Windows.

Step 1:
-------
Let's suppose that you have installed xampp in C:\ on Windows. So, your server
root directory will be C:\xampp\htdocs.

Step 2:
-------
Let's suppose that you have copied all search engine files in C:\search_engine.

Step 3:
-------
Now, let's create index_directory and its subdirectories in your server root
directory, which is C:\xampp\htdocs. The command and output is given below:

C:\search_engine>php create_index_directories.php C:\xampp\htdocs

Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/0
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/1
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/2
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/3
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/4
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/5
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/6
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/7
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/8
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/9
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/a
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/b
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/c
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/d
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/e
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/f
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/g
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/h
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/i
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/j
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/k
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/l
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/m
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/n
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/o
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/p
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/q
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/r
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/s
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/t
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/u
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/v
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/w
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/x
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/y
Created directory C:\xampp\htdocs/index_directory/z

Step 4:
-------
Now, let's suppose that all files to be indexed are in the directory files_to_be_indexed
in your server root directory (C:\xampp\htdocs\files_to_be_indexed). We can give files
also on command line but in this example I am giving a directory.

Now, the command to create index from the files in files_to_be_indexed is given below:

C:\search_engine>php create_index_or_add_to_existing_index.php -r -i C:\xampp\htdocs -p http://localhost -s C:\xampp\htdocs files_to_be_indexed

Step 5:
-------
Now, let's search for four words "server hello stop start".

The command and output is given below:

C:\search_engine>php search_index.php -i C:\xampp\htdocs server hello stop start

http://localhost/files_to_be_indexed/2/catalina_service.txt
http://localhost/files_to_be_indexed/3/ctlscript.html
http://localhost/files_to_be_indexed/readme_de.txt
http://localhost/files_to_be_indexed/readme_en.html
http://localhost/files_to_be_indexed/3/4/5/filezilla_start.html
http://localhost/files_to_be_indexed/3/4/5/filezilla_stop.html
http://localhost/files_to_be_indexed/3/4/mercury_start.html
http://localhost/files_to_be_indexed/3/catalina_stop.txt
http://localhost/files_to_be_indexed/2/apache_stop.txt
http://localhost/files_to_be_indexed/3/4/5/mysql_stop.html
http://localhost/files_to_be_indexed/3/4/mysql_start.html

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

_________End of ReadMe.txt_________
```

Comment: @mickmackusa In case of command line usage [$argc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argc.php) and [$argv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) are defined. We normally don't use this feature very often so I'm not surprised you weren't aware of it. I agree with you that nothing about this code is very elegant. It performs a very simple task yet needs a lot of code. What is good is that everything is explained quite well.

Comment: @KIKO, how do you describe elegant code? My coding style is to keep it simple so that it is easy to understand and easy to maintain. Elegant code can be sometimes complex and difficult to understand/maintain. Please read this discussion here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/97912/how-do-you-define-elegant-code. Also, can you please give me an example of elegant code by converting some of my code to elegant code. Thanks.

Comment: @mickmackusa, My coding style is to keep it simple so that it is easy to understand and easy to maintain. `[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]*` is easy to understand. If you had to write this regular expression then how would you write it? Can you please convert my inelegant pattern to elegant pattern which is also easy to understand? Thanks.

Comment: _"Elegant code is usually the result of careful analysis of the problem, and finding an algorithm and design which simplifies the code greatly."_ I personally don't find your directories and files elegant. The standard solution here would be to [use a database](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-full-text-search/). It could be a single file. That would be simple, elegant and powerful. I can however understand the aversion of some against using a database. They are rather complex. Nevertheless, databases are, in my opinion, an almost unavoidable standard programming tool in PHP.

Comment: @KIKO, So, basically what you are saying is that you don't like the architecture of this search engine. This is ok, I don't expect everyone to like my search engine's architecture. If I had used a database or a single file then the architecture of this search engine would have been different.

Comment: Now you make it sound very subjectively, but it is more than that. Your choice of storage is inefficient. Even Oliver Jones points this out in his very kind answer where he also introduces [OOP](https://www.phptutorial.net/php-oop/) to help you [separate concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Your software performs a basic task: Store URL's associated with words, but it needs many directories and thousands of files to do so. Why did you make that choice?

Comment: @KIKO, lets go with your proposal of single file architecture. In this architecture, if you have to add a new URL for a word then you have to read and write the whole file again with the new addition and you have to parse every line to match the word. There is no efficient way of updating a file. In my architecture, doing this is very simple and efficient - simply open the file whose name is that word and append the new URL. But I am not saying that my architecture is a superior architecture. I did this because it was very easy to implement - I implemented this in only one day.

Comment: Sorry, there is a misunderstanding. I meant that you could store [a database in a single file](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_php.htm). In that case it would be efficient. I agree that sticking to basic files is easy, when you're not used to dealing with databases.

Comment: @KIKO, why do you think that I haven't dealt with databases? Why would using a database be more efficient? Ultimately, databases store data in files itself, so database would also do the same - open file, read file, write/modify/append, etc. But I am doing this directly. Besides, databases involve usage of SQL language which adds more complexity/running time. Appending a row in a table in a database is slower than appending the row data directly in the file.

Comment: Yes, databases are more complex, but randomly adding rows in a database is probably faster than adding rows to many different files. The question here is whether you're using the right tool for the job. It is the same reason we often say you shouldn't store image files in a database, they are files and should be stored in the file system. You are storing data in a file system instead of in a database. The difference is subtle. In the end both are types of databases, but one is more suitable for large chunks of data referenced by a name, the other is better at storing tiny snippets of data.

Comment: @KIKO, you are just claiming that databases are faster than dealing with files directly. Do you have any proof such as any actual performance measurement?

Comment: No, of course I don't have performance data. Do you? Remember you started this, I quote: _"Appending a row in a table in a database is slower than appending the row data directly in the file."_ Yes, adding a single row will probably be faster, but it is never a single row, is it? In reality performance will depend on the situation. In some cases accessing files directly will be faster, in other cases using a database. I firmly believe that a database can easily outperform your filing system, for text searching, and it can do a lot more than just outperform it.

Comment: @KIKO, if you read the whole discussion, you will see that you brought up the "database is efficient" point first. Here are your comments - `Your choice of storage is inefficient`, `I meant that you could store a database in a single file. In that case it would be efficient.`.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I do think your method is inefficient, in the sense that it uses many files and directories with a lot of repeated content. Efficiency and speed are, as you point out, closely related, but they are not the same. Efficiency also covers things like resource usage, be it cpu cycles, memory, or disk space. I was referring to the latter. Anyway, I think we should end this discussion here, I don't see the point of arguing who said what when. You know what I think, and that should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Taken in the abstract, your indexing storage scheme is based on these primitives.

```php
/** return the index data given a word
 * @param string $word
 * @return array of URLs, empty array if $word not found
 * @throws Exception for storage-scheme problems
 */
function getFromIndex (string $word): array {}

/** insert an index item
 * @param string $word
 * @param string $url
 * @throws Exception for storage-scheme problems
 */
function insertToIndex (string $word, string $url) {}

/** remove an index item
 * @param string $word
 * @param string $url
 * @return boolean false if $word not found
 * @throws Exception for storage-scheme problems
 */
function removeFromIndex (string $word, string $url) {}
```

You would do well to implement a php class to expose these primitives. (If you don't know how to write a class, it is a skill very much worth your time to learn.) You can put your code for creating, maintaining, and reading your file system code into that class.  Using it might look like this:

```php
$index = new AmitIndex( '/path/to/index',  ​$forceCreation = true );
...
$index->insert( 'hello', $someUrl );
...
$resultArray = $index->get( 'hello' );
```

You would then use this php class in your command-line programs, and to implement your word-frequency logic. After you did that, you would get the following benefits:

1. Much simpler and shorter command line programs, easier to read and reason about. And, from the perspective of a code reviewer, far easier to understand.
2. Nothing in `$GLOBALS`, making it easier to use your class in other programs.
3. The ability to unit test your storage scheme.

You didn't ask about the performance of your scheme at scale.  I see a couple of hazards, though.

- Your method of deduplicating the `$url` entries for each word has **O(n)**  computational complexity. You read the entire file to find duplicate entries. Therefore your index-building complexity will be **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**. Your scheme's performance will collapse with many words it it.
- You're correct that it's possible to put many files in a directory. And, modern file systems can locate a file in a large directory in **O(log(n))** time. But rapidly opening / reading / writing / closing many files in a file system makes it do a lot of IO, which will slow down your system under heavy load.

The good news, though: You can reimplement your storage class to use some kind of highly efficient key-value store. Memcached? Redis? Sqlite? Any of these, used right, will take your complexity for insertion and lookup for many words down to **O(n log(n))**

Comment: Thanks for the review. But deduplicating will always be O(n) without any extra storage. Do you have any algorithm for deduplicating that is faster than O(n) that doesn't require any extra storage?